# duda sobre observables y subscripciones en angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript

al momento de usar el hook ondestroy estoy haciendo push de mis distintas subscripciones en un array y luego desuscribiendome de todas con un foreach pero mi duda es si yo no hiciera esto como puedo ver  en consola o donde sea el fludo de datos o el escape de memoria o la utilidad de esto que estoy haciendo no se si me explico ajajaja gracias un saludo

Comment: Puedes usar las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador para ver el consumo de  memoria de tu aplicación. Generalmente es necesario destruir subscripciones solo cuando estas no terminan solas, como algún socket, esto no significa que una operación larga no continue después de abandonar el componente. De ahí vienen los problemas de memoria.

Comment: entonces suguieres que destruya las subscripciones de igual forma para evitar problemas de memoria ?

Comment: Siendo sincero, es una nueva práctica que estoy implementando, pero si, lo recomiendo. Así te aseguras de no tener ninguna conexión fuera de tu control.